# red dotted wire connection in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using Simulink, simRF, DSP system toolbox and Communication system toolbox in my design, while i am connecting blocks with each other many shows red dotted lines instead of solid black lines although the blocks are taken from same library like while connecting mixer block output with the RF low pass filter input, shows a red dotted lines.

Comment: Make sure you don't try to connect *Physical conserving ports* and *Physical signal ports* (Simscape).

Answer (score 1):

The red dots means you can't connect the to blocks together. SimRF is based on the Simscape technology and so the connection between blocks aren't signal-based as in normal Simulink. Have a look at [Using SimRF Software for the First Time](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simrf/gs/using-simrf-software-for-the-first-time.html) in the documentation for the proper way to interface SimRF blocks to regular Simulink blocks.